# How to draw a rectangle with an angled corner in SVG

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms, clip-path

I'm using a clip path from an inline SVG to mask images with different aspect ratios on a website. The mask should hide the right bottom corner at a fixed angle (-15deg).

I cannot achieve that the right corner always stays at an angle, independently of the aspect ratio of the masked image.

My current SVG looks like this:

```
<svg height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipRight" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
         <rect x=0 y=0 width=1 height=0.5 /> 
         <rect x=0 y=0.5 width=1 height=0.5 transform="skewX(-15)" /> 
      </clipPath>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

and the css code looks like this:

```
.img-clip-right {
   clip-path: url(#clipRight);
}
```

The clip path should look like this

[image: rectangle sample]

I there  a way to  draw a line at a specific angle to the bottom end of the svg canvas without knowing the exact image dimension and without using javascript?

Comment: You specify the angle but you don't specify how much of the element should be clipped, How much do you want clipped? And does the amount depend on the aspect ratio of the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand why an SVG and masking is required.

This snippet just applies the clip path to the images.

It takes a corner off at 15degrees of the same area regardless of the size or aspect ratio of the image as the amount to be taken off is not specified in the question:

```css
.clipped {
  --x: 100px;
  --tan15: 0.267949192;
  --y: calc(var(--tan15) * var(--x));
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - var(--y)), calc(100% - var(--x)) 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<img class="clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
<img class="clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300">
<img class="clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200">
```

Comment: great answer. I just changed the first --x variable from pixels to %. In my case --x: 18%;

Comment: Unfortunately changing to % doesn't work. This is because it's a % of the width (OK so far) but when the system comes to use it in the y direction it assumes it's a % of the y direction. You'll notice that the angle is therefore not always 15degrees (it's OK on a square). This is why I asked about the amount required.

Comment: @A Haworth you are right!

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it with % of x axis width is to abandon polygon and look at overwriting the corner with a pseudo element on a containing div (using aspect-ratio to force it to the right dimensions). Would this be any help in your case?

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea about using SVG for clip-path, but maybe in this case a simpler solution could be ok. What about the [polygon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/polygon()) function? Here are three examples:

```css
body {
display: flex;
}

div {
 margin: 2px;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  background: CornflowerBlue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 0 100%);
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background: Peru;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 160px, 160px 100%, 0 100%);
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background: DarkSeaGreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 40px), calc(100% - 40px) 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use math to calculate the length of each triangle side, and use a `<path />` instead of `<rect />` to build a pentagon.

But in your question, you didn't specify the size of the white triangle, even with the same set of angles(15-90-75 in your case) it can be any size, and just scale. If you have a specific size of any triangles side, that would be a clearly determined task.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the masking should be responsive to multiple images with different sizes

Comment: @denoise it will be responsive, but to know proportions you need to define % ratio of any triangle side to corresponding square side